# Redis key prefix when using it as a PHP session handler...?

Tags: php, session, redis

I'm using Redis as a PHP session handler.

In my Apache vhost I have the following:
php_value session.save_path "tcp://10.179.192.173:6379"
php_value session.save_handler "redis"

The default key prefix for PHP sessions is "PHPREDIS_SESSION:".

How do I change this?

I've seen various examples tacking on arguments to the save_path such as "tcp://10.179.192.173:6379?timeout=1" but can't see find anything on setting the prefix.

The following blog post mentions that it is possible, but doesn't explain how:
http://phpave.com/redis-as-a-php-session-handler/#.Uos6xGRmWjQ

Anyone know the answer?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer, reading the manual.

For anyone who's looking for this see: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#php-session-handler

Under the title, "PHP Session handler", lies a list of possible arguments.

Answer (score 12):

And the answer is to use the prefix in `session.save_path`.

```
tcp://10.179.192.173:6379?prefix=PREFIX_SESSION:
```

Don't forget the colon `:`